# R: How to make aggregate pivot table

Tags: r

Let's say we have dataframe

```
  product qua    color  month
1 Box     3       red    jan  
2 Box     14      blue   jan
3 Box     22      green  jan
4 Box     10       red   feb  
5 Box     12      blue   feb
6 Box     36      green  feb
7 Box     31       red   mar  
8 Box     1      blue    mar
9 Box     7      green   mar
```

How to group data this way:

```
           jan feb mar
  box red   3   10  31
      blue  14  12  1
      green 22  36  7
```

Thanks a lot in advance)

Comment: In your sample data, there is no value for e.g. `color == "red & month == "feb" |  month == "mar"` etc.. Nevertheless, you might try `library(reshape2); dcast(df, formula = product + color ~ month, value.var = 'qua', fun.aggregate = sum)`. Replace `sum` by any other aggregation function as you like.

Comment: How do you get 10 for 'box red' at 'feb'?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!  possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: @markus you almost close) thank you
but it is also important to group value = box and print it once in column, like in description. Any idea?

Comment: @IvanBukata You mean this aggregation should be done for different levels of `product`? Can you show some example data? Use `dput(df)` to share it.

Comment: `xtabs(qua ~ color + month, dat)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data:

```
df<-
data.table::fread("id product qua    color  month
1 Box     3       red    jan  
2 Box     14      blue   jan
3 Box     22      green  jan
4 Box     10       red   feb  
5 Box     12      blue   feb
6 Box     36      green  feb
7 Box     31       red   mar  
8 Box     1      blue    mar
9 Box     7      green   mar")[,-1] %>% setDF
```

code:

```
df %>% 
mutate(color = factor(color,levels=unique(na.omit(color))), month = factor(month,levels=unique(na.omit(month)))) %>%
spread(month, qua)
```

result:

```
  product color jan feb mar
1     Box   red   3  10  31
2     Box  blue  14  12   1
3     Box green  22  36   7
```

To have the Box only once:

Save the above to `result` for e.g..

```
result$product[duplicated(result$product)]<-""
```

New result:

```
  product color jan feb mar
1     Box   red   3  10  31
2          blue  14  12   1
3         green  22  36   7
```

Comment: great, man) thanks a lot, but is there any idea how to print Box once? (it is important option for report's owner)

Comment: look at my edit  @IvanBukata

Comment: Elrice - thank you very much) but ...there is last one) your issue works if it is only one product, but can it work for 2? Box and data and 2 rows below new product, cups, for example with same properties?

Comment: @IvanBukata please make sure to make an example that covers all your needs. See my edit: You can use: `result$product[duplicated(result$product)]<-""`